# How do you reset an event?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm building a calculator. I can't get it to display the 2nd number that the user wants to calculate. For example, if the user wants to calculate 10 * 2. I want to display the 10. After they click *, I want to store 10 for later use, and display the 2.

```
//select screen display element
let screen = document.querySelector(".screen");

//select all calculator number keys
let numberKeys = document.querySelectorAll(".keys");

//select operator elements
let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operators");


numberKeys.forEach((key) => {
  key.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    screen.innerText += e.target.innerText;
  });
});

operators.forEach((op) => {
  op.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    screenValue += screen.innerText;
    operator = e.target.innerText;
    secondNumber += screen.innerText;
  });
});
```

Comment: Put it in a global variable. Isn't that what you're doing with `screenValue += screen.innerText`?

Comment: I can store the 1st number fine using screenValue.I want to reset the screen display after the operator is clicked. But after user clicks the operator, I can't display the 2nd number on the screen or store it, because screen is still displaying that 1st number.

Comment: `screen.innerText = '';` will empty it.